# about jQuery timeout error process

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout, xmlhttprequest

Recently, I found some error about timeout.

Please see below code.

- jQuery timeout : 5000 ms
- Servlet sleep : 10000 ms

Client side Javascript

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
    url: "http://localhost:8888/{mydomain}",
    timeout : 5000,
    error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
        switch(xhr.status) {
            case 0 :
                $('#msg').append("0");
                break;
            case 404:
                $('#msg').append("404 ERROR."); 
                break;
            case 500:
                $('#msg').append("500 ERROR.");
                break;
            case 408:
                $('#msg').append("408 ERROR.");
                break;              
            default :
                $('#msg').append(xhr.status);
                break;
        }
    }       
});

$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType:"JSON",
            data:{send a some data},
            success:function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        })      
});
```

Java process

```
@Path("/{mydomain}")
public class DummyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getMethod() throws Exception {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);            
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
        }
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

But, error is different between Safari and Firefox.

1. Safari (timeout error: I think, this result is right.)

   ```
   > GET //localhost:8888/{mydomain} Aborted
   ```
2. Firefox(success, but some error occured)

   ```
   > GET //localhost:8888/{mydomain} 200 OK 10.01s
   uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.status]" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: //localhost:8888/{mydomain}/ajax.html :: anonymous :: line 20" data: no]
   ```

My System Info

MacOSX : 10.6.5
Browser: Safari 5.0.3, Firefox 3.6.8

Comment: yea, that same thing happened to me. And in IE7 the timeout error is undefined. and the xhr.status is not ready or something like that. i just removed the timeout, cause i never really knew how long it would take anyway.

Comment: @morniooji , what are you doing with the errors on the UI , based on the error type are you doing some popup or its just for learning purposes.

Comment: @gov, it's just a sample. :-)

Comment: on crome8.0.552.231(for mac), 
>> ajax.html:13Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Comment: I've just upgrade jQuery from 1.4.3 to 1.4.4 (no min), but result is same.

Comment: @morinooji , send you results to firefox, chrome team, probably they can come back with some definete answer